# Automate cloud auth login with no human interaction

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a virtual machine which runs the scripts daily using cloud services, but for every 150 days I need to manually remote login to VM and do **gcloud auth login**, and all the scripts fail if I don’t do this step, is there a way to write an shell or Python script and use it with crown job to complete this step with no human interaction. Manually I need to select the link which will open browser and select **Allow** but can I automate this using no-launch-browser( still no human interaction should be there).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot configure **user** credentials to automatically re-authenticate. Those credentials require human interaction.

Instead, configure the CLI to use a service account.

[gcloud auth activate-service-account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account)

If you are running in Google Cloud, you can use the attached service account.

[Compute Engine Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts)

Using either method means that the CLI will automatically renew credentials.